# How to replace using regular expressions via c#

Tags: c#

I have string like

"FirstName=Alpha&LastName=Beta&**Email=blah@blah.com**&Country=UnitedStates&**Email=foo@foobar.com**"

I need some help with the regular expression with extracts the email value.

I used the pattern "Email=(.*?)&" but it needs an & at the end of the string.

My Code to replace the email value

```
Regex.Replace(text, "email=(.*?)&", ComputeReplacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Any help with regex?

Comment: You have two different emails in the example string.  What are you trying to replace them with?

Comment: I want to replace the email with a text like "something"

Answer (score 4):

Strings in .NET are <s>invariant</s> immutable, and [the `input` parameter to this overload of `Regex.Replace` is not a `ref` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475(v=vs.110).aspx). Instead, the changed string will be returned by `Regex.Replace`. Simply assign it:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "email=(.*?)&", ComputeReplacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I'm assuming (though we all know what effect that has on u and me) that `ComputeReplacement` is a `MatchEvaluator`.

Comment: I'm going to be an insufferable pedant and point out that strings are *immutable*.  Invariant usually refers to generics (invariant is what you get when something is neither covariant nor contravariant).

Comment: @Kyle Thank you. I have some kind of weird aphasia with that word. Your pedantry is entirely sufferable.

Comment: My question should have been more clear. The given code does not work for the input string because the second occurrence of email does not end with a string. Need help with regex and then I need to replace all the email values with a computed value like email.Length.

Comment: The regex that worked for me is - @"email=(?<match>[^&]*)&?" and then i used below to get it to work.
 MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    inputText.Replace(match.Result(string.Format("${{{0}}}", namedGroup)), GetScrubbedPIIString(match.Result(string.Format("${{{0}}}", namedGroup))));
                }

namedGroup is "match"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could take a look into the [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) method, as it can handle the same task without the regular expression:

```
var query = "FirstName=Alpha&LastName=Beta&Email=blah@blah.com&Email=foo@foobar.com";
var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
foreach (var email in parsed.GetValues("Email"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(email);
}
```

This approach also takes care of the URL encoding; for instance, try with `"FirstName=Some%20Name"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the emails:

```
string input = "FirstName=Alpha&LastName=Beta&Email=blah@blah.com&Country=UnitedStates&Email=foo@foobar.com";
Dictionary<string,string> emails = input.Split(new char[] { '&' }).Where(param => param.ToLower().Contains("email")).Select(param => param.Split(new char[] { '=' })).ToDictionary(x=> x[1], x=> x[0]);
foreach (string email in emails.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you split the string before using your Regex, there is no need anymore for an & at the end of the string (you will end up with an extra & at the end of the resulting string, but you can check for that if it is an issue):

```
String input = "FirstName=Alpha&LastName=Beta&Email=blah@blah.com&Country=UnitedStates&Email=foo@foobar.com";
String output = "";
foreach (string element in input.Split('&')) {
    output += Regex.Replace(element, "email=(.*?)&", ComputeReplacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) + "&"; }
```